# Statement is being skipped when running in Javascript

Tags: javascript, game-development

I want to create a simple and quick mini rock paper scissors game. How it works is, when the user clicks the START GAME button it gives the user a random item for example **"rock"**. When the user receives the item, the id **"computer-item"** should then display:

> **"Computer: Processing output..."**

After 3 seconds it then shows the computer's random item for example **paper**. This issue is found in the **startGame()** function. How do I get this to be like that?

I tried using setTimeout so that it would hopefully display after 3 seconds. Any help at all would be much appreciated as I am kind of new to JavaScript.

JavaScript:

```js
let p_item = document.getElementById("player-item");
let cpu_item = document.getElementById("computer-item");
let items = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];

function getPlayerHand() {
  //for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
  let p_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  return items[p_index];
}

function getCPUHand() {
  //for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
  let cpu_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  return items[cpu_index];
}

function startGame() {
  p_item.textContent = "Player: " + getPlayerHand();
  cpu_item.textContent = "Computer: Processing output...";
  setTimeout(getCPUHand, 3000);
  cpu_item.textContent = "Computer: " + getCPUHand();
}

function playAgain() {
  clearTimeout(getCPUHand);
  p_item.textContent = "Player: ";
  cpu_item.textContent = "Computer: ";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="player-item">Player:</p>
  <p id="computer-item">Computer:</p>

  <button onclick="startGame()">START GAME</button>

  <p>GAME HAS FINISHED
    <button onclick="playAgain()">PLAY AGAIN</button>
  </p>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The argument to `clearTimeout()` shouldn't be a function, it's the timer ID that was previously returned by `setTimeout()`.

Comment: `setTimeout(getCPUHand, 3000);` will schedule `getCPUHand()` to be called after three seconds. Yet at the very next line you call the same function *immediately*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout()` runs `getCPUHand()` 3 seconds later, but it doesn't wait for it. It returns immediately, and then the line `cpu_item.textContent = "Computer: " + getCPUHand();` runs. You should put the code that displays the computer hand in the `setTimeout()` call.

The argument to `clearTimeout()` should be the value that was returned by `setTimeout()`. So assign that value to a global variable, which you use when restarting.

```js
let p_item = document.getElementById("player-item");
let cpu_item = document.getElementById("computer-item");
let items = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
let timer;

function getPlayerHand() {
  //for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
  let p_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  return items[p_index];
}

function getCPUHand() {
  //for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
  let cpu_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  return items[cpu_index];
}

function startGame() {
  p_item.textContent = "Player: " + getPlayerHand();
  cpu_item.textContent = "Computer: Processing output...";
  timer = setTimeout(() => cpu_item.textContent = "Computer: " + getCPUHand(), 3000);
}

function playAgain() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  p_item.textContent = "Player: ";
  cpu_item.textContent = "Computer: ";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="player-item">Player:</p>
  <p id="computer-item">Computer:</p>

  <button onclick="startGame()">START GAME</button>

  <p>GAME HAS FINISHED
    <button onclick="playAgain()">PLAY AGAIN</button>
  </p>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling setTimeout, but the script executes the next line immediately, which already sets the value. Can you try this and see if it works:

```
  function startGame() {
    p_item.textContent = "Player: " + getPlayerHand();
    cpu_item.textContent = "Computer: Processing output...";
    setTimeout(() => {
      cpu_item.textContent = "Computer: " + getCPUHand();
    }, 3000);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let p_item = document.getElementById("player-item");
let cpu_item = document.getElementById("computer-item");
let items = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
let timeoutHandler = null;

function getPlayerHand() {
  //for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
  let p_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  return items[p_index];
}

function getCPUHand() {
  //for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
  let cpu_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  return items[cpu_index];
}

function startGame() {
  p_item.textContent = "Player: " + getPlayerHand();
  cpu_item.textContent = "Computer: Processing output...";
  timeoutHandler = setTimeout(()=>{
getCPUHand();
  cpu_item.textContent = "Computer: " + getCPUHand();
}, 3000);

}

function playAgain() {
  clearTimeout(timeoutHandler );
  p_item.textContent = "Player: ";
  cpu_item.textContent = "Computer: ";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="player-item">Player:</p>
  <p id="computer-item">Computer:</p>

  <button onclick="startGame()">START GAME</button>

  <p>GAME HAS FINISHED
    <button onclick="playAgain()">PLAY AGAIN</button>
  </p>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```